# Problem with css propriety "background-clip: text;" and W3C validator

Tags: css

I would like to put on a text a gradient of two colors.
After some searches, here is the css code I got:

```css
p{
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-clip:text;
    -webkit-background-clip:text;
  }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus elementum vitae sem at ornare. Cras in massa et ante suscipit dignissim. Donec finibus, erat ac vehicula fringilla, magna nibh molestie est, sit amet pellentesque magna augue in lectus. Sed volutpat enim augue, tempor luctus lectus laoreet a. Integer et nibh nunc. Quisque ac est a sapien blandit rhoncus. Cras maximus mi eu quam auctor facilisis. Aenean a nisl lacus. Vivamus elementum aliquet magna, vel efficitur augue luctus vitae. Sed sit amet lectus feugiat, gravida urna id, imperdiet neque. In nec nulla et ante tristique dapibus eu ac eros. Vestibulum vitae tellus mattis, facilisis massa a, mollis ante. Curabitur et orci laoreet, porttitor ipsum ac, mattis elit. Proin in feugiat dolor, non volutpat velit.</p>
```

I got the desired result, but on W3C validator, "background-clip: text;" does not pass.
I would like to know if there is another way to achieve this result but that goes to W3C.
Thank you in advance
PS: I must only use HTML/ CSS 
PS2: Sorry if the question has already been asked.

Comment: don't worry about the validator, it's not up to date so you will always get error for valid properties

Comment: but replace `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` with`color:transparent`

Comment: I would like to but I was forced to have a code that passes the validator and I really need this feature. Is there no alternative ?

Comment: *I was forced* --> explain to the person that force you and we will probably understand something new and will no more force you

Comment: This project is part of the training that I am going through and the validator is one of the validation requirements. Sorry for my english, I'm not very good

Comment: And on the model that I was provided with there is text in degraded.

Comment: it’s good
the effect appears just with "-webkit-background-clip".
The "background-clip" line was useless and my code goes to W3C.

Comment: *The "background-clip" line was useless* --> it's not useless, it's mandatory. Too bad people are leading you to the wrong way with such requirements ....

Comment: You’re probably right but I can’t do anything about it, if I don’t validate my project I won’t have my diploma and if my code doesn’t pass on W3C I don’t validate my project. The programme of French universities is often behind in this kind of field. 
Thanks anyway for your help.